# Cannot redefine property in Node.js (though can in browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to redefine an existing property inside a class (it's for experimenting purposes; I know I shouldn't).

For some reason, the following code works in a browser (Chrome), but not Node.js (v18.12.0).

```
function re(instance, name, val) {
    let _value = val;
    Object.defineProperty(instance, name, {
        get: () => { return _value },
        set: (v) => { return _value = v }
    })
    return val;
}

class A {
    prop = re(this, 'prop', 456)
}

const a = new A()
console.log(a.prop)
```

The Chrome console output would be `456`, but Node.js will be like nope, no redefining today, instead take this: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: prop`. Which is sad. I tested on my PC plus at some online Node.js interpreter (replit.com).

Comment: It throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: prop` when I try to run it in Chrome.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "prop"` in Firefox

Comment: Contrary to your claim that _the following code works in a browser (Chrome)_ I observe the same TypeError, when running in Chrome.  It's literally the same JavaScript engine as Node.js, so I don't know why it would be different.  How are you observing that it works in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to the provide `configurable` attribute.

```
function re(instance, name, val) {
    let _value = val;
    Object.defineProperty(instance, name, {
        get: () => { return _value },
        set: (v) => { return _value = v },
        configurable: true
    }, )
    return val;
}

class A {
    prop = re(this, 'prop', 456)
}

const a = new A()
console.log(a.prop)
```

You can refer to the MDN documentation: *[TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "x"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_redefine_property)*

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot edit my question, nor ask new one because got block for it :(... but maybe you know, why in nodejs the property will get overwritten (a.prop = 1) but in browser the setter will be used instead? ( https://pastebin.com/K4tQv18q this code gets different results in node and chrome) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @r32 I see the same result for both. [Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If25v.png) and [Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWABd.png)

Comment: @r32 You can still edit your existing questions. In fact, that's what you're supposed to do to get the block lifted.